# How to set up propel 1.7 in localhost

Tags: php, windows, cmd, propel

I'm new in Propel. i'm using proper version 1.7. I created schema.xml, but when i run command to create model. It's not working. I saw an message: 'propel-gen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
This is directory: http://prntscr.com/51iy70.
how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if your current dir in CMD is the one in the screenshot, then the command is `bin\propel-gen`

Comment: Execution of target "check-buildprops-for-propel-gen" failed for the following r
eason: e:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\bookstore1\generator\bin\..\build.xml:96:22: e:\
Projects\xampp\htdocs\bookstore1\generator\bin\..\build.xml:96:22: No project di
rectory specified.

Comment: Check the value of "propel.output.dir" in your "build.properties" file.  I also suggest that you run the build command in the same folder as your schema file(schema.xml), and that models folder is a sub-folder in this folder